# Getting SAS tokens in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Is there any way to list SAS tokens of a storage account in Azure CLI? I can generate one and it spits out the generated token immediately. However, there seems to be no way to list/show/get the same token later using Azure CLI. I see it's possible in REST API but not in Azure CLI.

Answer (score 1):

There is no azure cli command to  list SAS tokens of a storage account, all the commands [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest).

If necessary, you could post your idea in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

SAS tokens must be generated for a specified scope and permissions, as well as a time frame in which they are valid. 
Listing SAS tokens for a storage account is NOT possible as a limitless number of tokens are valid.

To get a SAS-token for the same scope, you can pass in the same [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-generate-sas) from the previous generation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure we are on the same page; which REST API is it that your are not able to reach from the Azure CLI?

Best regards,
Johan Stenberg

Comment: What I am saying is there is no command in Azure CLI to list SAS tokens.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to track already issues SAS tokens. The rest API which you are referring is also created new token, It will not list the existing tokens.